# Handle public external DTDs in .Net via XmlResolver

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dtd

my XML is referencing a DTD like this:

< !DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//OWNER//NAME//EN" "http://invalid/path/to.dtd">

The DTD is not available via the given URL, but I can download it to my disc. I tried to implement a custom XmlResolver to load the DTD, but it does not work. My custom XmlResolver implements GetEntity and via the debugger I can see the following calls comming in:

1. The requested uri is the xml document to be loaded. I open a stream for this document and return it. That works fine.
2. The DTD is requested as a URI of the format "file:///absolut/path/to.xml/-//OWNER//NAME//EN". I'm using a regular expression to check for -//.*?// which works fine, but looks not very clean for me. But if the DTD is selfcontained, it works.
3. The DTD is referencing modules.ent. That results in a call to GetEntity with an URI of: "file:///absolut/path/to.xml/-//OWNER//NAME//modules.ent". Obviously now it get's quite strange to reconstruct the intension of the path.

Any hint how to implement that in a correct way? I think public external DTDs are quite common in the publishing sector so there must be a clean solution!?

cheers,
Achim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"file:///absolut/path/to.xml/-//OWNER//NAME//EN"` is a concatenation of the SYSTEM and the PUBLIC identifiers. Generally, you want to look at one or the other, not both, and certainly not as a single string. When you say "DTD is requested as a URI of the format," it is not clear who is doing the requesting. It appears that the calling code concatenates SYSTEM and PUBLIC.

If you have the DTD as a disk file and all you need to do is map one URI to another, you can override `ResolveUri()` instead of the full `GetEntity()`. `GetEntity()` is more useful if you have resources that are inaccessible as straightforward URIs, e.g. you compute the content of the resource at runtime, you fetch it from a database, you use a non-standard URL scheme and protocol like svn: etc.